# How to create an alias for a class in jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery, alias

How to create an alias for a class in jQuery so that its acted upon by all functions as they would to the original class.

Consider the following.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(document).on('click', '.test', function(){
    console.log('working...');
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.test', function(){
    console.log('working...');
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="newAliasClass" name="alias"/>
```

I want the class "newAliasClass" to be an alias of class "test", and be done on page load.

**One Option I have which is not what i want.**
I want the input field to only have "newAliasClass" on it, and not "test".

```
$('.newAliasClass').addClass('test');
```

How can I do this so that the element, "Input Field", only has the class, "newAliasClass" on it, but "newAliasClass" representing "test".

Thanks.

Comment: At best this question looks like a XY problem. At worst it's "*not smart*".

Comment: quite simply you cannot do what you want.  there is no practical use for it.  there will be a better way to do whatever your reason for this is.
Edit: The reason you cannot do this,  is because class is an identifier that's not unique.  if you need to add extra identifiers,  you add them using addClass as you mentioned,  if you only have 1 class on the object,  then you will only ever be able to reference that object with that class (or ID, but we arn't talking about ID's).
Edit2:  i mean you could add before the `$(document)` something along the lines of `var test = $('.newAliasClass')`

Comment: @Nikerym, "there is no practical use for it", there certainly exists a practical use, just because you can't see one doesn't mean there's no practical use.

Comment: @Relm Feel free to enlighten me why it would be practical to have a single class(non unique identifier) rather then an ID?  and restrict it to only 1 value?